# 2 objects field mapping dynamically

Tags: apex

i have one requirement on dynamic field mapping, i have 2 objects, Main_object and Staging_object, i will insert records in staging object by using integration, after record get insertd in staging object , i will replicate same record into Main_object , to active this i have to map 20 fields before compare records example: mainobj.field1__C= stageobj.feild1__c .. till 20 fields, can any one suggest me how to achive this finctionaly dynamically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
public static sobject cloneFields(sobject input, sobject output){
    map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(input.getsobjecttype().getDescribe().getname().tolowercase()).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    map <String, Schema.SObjectField> outputfieldMap = schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(output.getsobjecttype().getDescribe().getname().tolowercase()).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for (string field : fieldMap.keySet()) {
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fieldmap.get(field).getDescribe();
        if (fieldDescribe.isUpdateable() && fieldDescribe.isAutoNumber() == false && fieldDescribe.isCalculated() == false && fieldDescribe.isCustom()) {
            if (outputfieldmap.containsKey(field)) output.put(field,input.get(field));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```